# Bug Tracking for Windows and SVN

Tags: windows, visual-studio, svn, visualsvn-server, bug-tracking

I'm working as part of a volunatry team creating an open source product with a permissive license. We are currently using Visual SVN Server/TortoiseSVN for source control and TeamCity for our continuous integration builds.

I would like to add a bug tracking component into the mix that will integrate into SVN. Ideally, I'd like to use FogBugz but we have no budget. So, I need an alternative. The requirements are:

- Must be free or have a free version supporting at least 20 developers (we're volunteers!)
- Must integrate with VisualSVN Server
- Must run on Windows
- I prefer Microsoft technology (ASP.Net over PHP; SQL Server over MySQL, etc) because we are a Microsoft shop, we have experience with those tools and already have them installed.
- Must be able to work with a geographically distributed team
- Must work with Express editions of Visual Studio (the developers don't all have the Pro version so we can't rely on Visual Studio add-ins).

I'd like The Community's recommendations, please, for products that meet all of the above requirements.

[Clarification: our license is very close (though not word-for-word) to the MIT license.]

Comment: Fogbugz does have a free version that allows 2 logins. You can also ask them for a free license if you are charity/non-profit etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) is [free for open source projects](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/licensing.jsp#nonprofit) and will run on Windows. Subversion integration is available and provided through a [plugin](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/JIRA+Subversion+Plugin?pageVersion=122).

Comment: [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) uses JIRA for their publiclly accessible bug tracking system. From an end user perspective, its a great product.

Comment: I'm accepting this as my preferred answer because Jira has a no-brainer self-contained install, works on Windows, has an SVN plugin supported by the vendor and does have free licenses for open-source projects. I'm still uncertain whether they will accept _our_ open source licens as it is not one of teh officially recognised ones, although it is very similar to the MIT license.

Comment: Another thing I liked about Jira is that it lets me use my Microsoft SQL 2005 server as the back-end database and doesn't force me to install MySQL. The installation is self-contained and very clean.

Comment: Good news, Atlassian accepted my request for an open-source license, so this option has worked out well for me.

Comment: JIRA is a bit an overkill and kinda feels little bit clunky.

Answer (score 8):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/): It is not a Microsoft technology but will integrate well into SVN. There are not many free bug tracking software's that are free on Microsoft technology.

Comment: Trac, while not MS stack worked great for me integrating with SVN.  I used a hosted plan that provided trac and svn.  I liked it.  I have since used only Fogbugz, but would go back to trac if financial needs forced me to do so.

Answer (score 3):

- [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)
- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)

Comment: I personally like Redmine over Trac because of the ability to have multiple projects in the same installation, but that may not apply in this question's situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/).

- Is free
- I do not know if integrates with SVN... but I suppose the answer is YES.
- Runs on Windows - you must set up few
  components, but it actually runs
  prety well on IIS, however
  installation is a bit tricky.
  Bugzilla is Perl and MySQL. However,
  as I said I had installed succesfully
  Bugzilla on Windows 2003.
  Installation of MySql and Perl does
  not take a lot of server resources -
  we had those two on our ASP.NET +
  MSSQL test server, and no performacne
  drop had been observed.
- Works with    distributed team.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but those external dependencies were a real negative for me. I decided to go with Jira for the completely integrated installation experience with no external dependencies. Jira runs on Tomcat+JRE but everything is bundled into one setup package, it is as easy as falling off a log. Also, Jira supports my existing SQL Server infrastructure and doesn't force me to install a whole new database server for some quasi-religious agenda. I hate it when the tail wags the dog. Jira works well, it works with my systems and it is self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

Try [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net), you can even get the hosted way for free if your project is not that big in size.

Comment: This seemed like a good product but I had no end of problems with the registration/login. When creating a new hosted system, the confirmation email never arrived. If I were going to use this system, I would not use the hosted option - but then the on-premise option doesn't run on Windows. But, +1 for a good suggestion, others may have better luck with it.